# Facebook Comment Section not showing up

Tags: html, css, facebook, plugins

I need help regarding the facebook comment section. So, I added the plugin for my youtube video on my website. But, it's not showing up. I already added the script just below the

Code:

```
<div id = "video">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WEY4E6bIi4s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEY4E6bIi4s" data-numposts="5"></div>
</div>

#fb {
margin: 0% 15% 0% 15%;
background-color: #fff;
}

#fbComment {
clear: both;
margin-top: 2%;
margin: 2% 25% 0% 25%;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 2%;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using ?

Comment: Hello, I'm using Chrome! It doesn't work on Edge too :(

Comment: Oh oh! Correction, it works on edge but not on chrome.

Comment: Do you have an adblocker installed ? It may prevent the script from loading.

Comment: IT DID WORK WHEN I TURNED IT OFF. Thank you so much! Thank you! ♥